# Is there any why to use substr in group by clause?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have a table T and a column in that table C this column C is combination of two strings (say, country, city) now I want to get the count of total entries for particular country.some thing like below

> select count(*), country from T group by substr(country, 0, 20);

How to achieve this?

Comment: Answer me this. Suppose you have 2 `country` values, `country1234567890123 city1` and `country1234567890123 city2`. Now in output, you need count of `country1234567890123` as 2. But do you need `country1234567890123 city1` or `country1234567890123 city2` to be displayed too? If yes then which one?

Comment: Is it possible to show country1234567890123 city1 -1 country1234567890123 city2- 1 where 1 is count? I don't think so. Tim's inner query gives the country1234567890123  - 2

Comment: Tim's inner query is giving you the result you asked for in the question. So `distinct(substr(country, 0, 20))` would be `2`. And if you want to display the count of just `country` then why would you go for group by `substr(country, 0, 20)` in the first place. Doesnt make sense.

Comment: Try this. Recreate some sample data in http://sqlfiddle.com and show what exact output you expect based on that.

Answer (score 3):

You can `JOIN` the `T` table to the query in your original question on the substring of the `country` field:

```
select t1.cntCount, t2.country
from
(
    select count(*) as cntCount, substr(country, 0, 20) as cntSub
    from T
    group by substr(country, 0, 20)
) t1
left join
    country t2
on t1.cntSub = substr(t2.country, 0, 20)
```

Comment: Since the table is huge, I can't do joins.

Comment: The first subquery in my answer is not much different from what you had, and I don't imagine doing the `LEFT JOIN` will incur too much of a penalty.  Do you have any indices set up?  Why exactly can't do you do a join?

Comment: Now that I think of it, your first subquery is enough to give the answer. My answer is moot now :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select distinct(derived_country),count(*) as countOfCountry from 
    (select T.*,substr(country, 0, 20) as derived_country from T) d
group by derived_country
```

Comment: This query is extremely clever, but won't it return the substring version of the `country` field rather than the full name?

Comment: Yes I agree with you. But if `substr(country,0,20)` is same for 2 `country`, but the actual value of `country` is different, in that case, we can't display both `country` value in a group by output. And if we group by `country`, it defies the logic OP is asking for. Anyways, we can use an aggregate function to display any one of the country of distinct(derived_country) list.

Comment: Nice catch.  Ironically, my query also handles this case and duplicate substrings would be grouped out.

Comment: (Upvoted, thanks, this example helped me). Is that isolated `d` a typo?

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(substr(country, 0, 20)), country from T group by substr(country, 0, 20);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```sql
--  S a m p l e   D a t a :
WITH
    tbl AS
        (
            Select 1 "ID", 'Jack' "PERSON", 'Texas,Dallas' "COMES_FROM" From Dual Union All
            Select 2 "ID", 'John' "PERSON", 'Texas,Dallas' "COMES_FROM" From Dual Union All
            Select 3 "ID", 'Jane' "PERSON", 'Washington,Seatle' "COMES_FROM" From Dual Union All
            Select 4 "ID", 'Mick' "PERSON", 'Massachusets,Boston' "COMES_FROM" From Dual Union All
            Select 5 "ID", 'Kate' "PERSON", 'Massachusets,Boston' "COMES_FROM" From Dual Union All
            Select 6 "ID", 'Mike' "PERSON", 'Massachusets,Boston' "COMES_FROM" From Dual 
        )

--  M a i n   S Q L :
Select  SubStr(COMES_FROM, 1, InStr(COMES_FROM, ',') - 1) "STATE",
        Count(*) "PERSONS"
From    tbl
Group By  SubStr(COMES_FROM, 1, InStr(COMES_FROM, ',') - 1)
Order By  SubStr(COMES_FROM, 1, InStr(COMES_FROM, ',') - 1)

--  R e s u l t :
STATE                  PERSONS
------------------- ----------
Massachusets                 3 
Texas                        2 
Washington                   1
```